# How to partially cover a given shape with fixed number of circles?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I am not sure if it is proper to ask for help on algorithm here, but could anyone give me some guide, or just tell me where I could find such a kind of guide? Thanks a lot!

The problem is like this: given a fixed number of circles, I need an algorithm to find an optimal set of positions and radius of these circles to cover a given shape, so the error area (the parts of the circles outside the given shape + the parts of the shape not covered by these circles) is minimal? Circles could overlap.

Comment: What kinds of shapes are these? Polygons? Pixels from an image? What?

Comment: Just arbitrarily shapes.

Comment: Does each circle get its own radius?  Or all the same radius?

Comment: Could get its own radius.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a trivial problem and there is certainly no simple analytic solution. For example: even the simplest version - one circle and one simple connected area isn't necessarily easy to solve depending on the shape of the area. There will also typically be numerous false minimums.

I would suggest that simulated annealing would be a suitable technique to find a good (if not the optimal) solution. Effectively, with n circles you are exploring a wildly varying function of 3n variables (x, y, and r for each circle) and simulated annealing is a fairly efficient way of exploring such an environment.